# Densifying a GPS track

Tags: gps, gps-track-editor

I have GPS data of a route which is about 32 km. The number of recorded gps waypoints for this route is 1670. But I would like to have a waypoint every 10 meters. So the number of waypoints for this route should be increased to 3200.

Comment: You're just basically looking to add midpoints to the existing points? Or are you using a more sophisticated algorithm to determine the 10m points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you familiar with QGIS? There is a plugin for it called QChainage, it will place points along a line for you at a specified interval. With this you could generate points along your route every 10m.

[Here is a link to the plugin](https://github.com/mach0/qchainage), but you should install it through QGIS plugin manager.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about this plugin. I think it would solve my problem.